# how do I automate the number of columns and rows while plotting in python (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

While plotting with matplotlib, each I have different number of columns and rows, I have to edit my script. Below I have posted the script which has 5 columns. But if I have file which has 7 columns and I want to plot 1st column against 7th column, then I have to edit my code again as in example: c0[7],c7=float(elements[7]), C7.append(c7),etc. Is there a way to automate it? so I won't have to keep changing my code each time I have different number of rows and cols. Thank you

As input parameters, you can have your data file and provide which columns you want to plot for example (1st col against 6th one). Script will take care of number of columns by itself.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
infile = open("ewcd.txt","r")
data = infile.readlines()


C0=[]
C1=[]
C2=[]
C3=[]
C4=[]

for line in data:
elements = line.split()
try:
    c0=float(elements[0])
    c1 = float(elements[1])
    c2=float(elements[2])
    c3=float(elements[3])
    c4=float(elements[4])

    C0.append(c0)
    C1.append(c1)
    C2.append(c2)
    C3.append(c3)   
    C4.append(c4)
except IndexError:
    pass


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.yscale('log')
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=13)
plt.plot(C0,C1,'b-')
plt.plot(C0,C2,'g-')
```

Comment: In your script, you plot the 2nd and 3rd columns against the 1st. The 4th and 5th columns are ignored. What would the general rule be?

Comment: Here, "ewcd.txt" has 5 columns, so my script will work and plot without any problem. But if I have data file which has less than 5 columns, then script will complain. Same thing with, if I have script with more than 5 columns, my script will not work. So I want to automate number of columns so script doesn't depend on data file.

Comment: Where will it break if there's more than 5 columns?

Comment: if I have more than five columns in data file, and I want to plot first column against the sixth one, then I cannot use this script. I will have to modify it as I was saying in description.

Comment: Now you are plotting the 2nd and 3rd columns, but later you want to plot the 6th one, without changing the script. Hence my question, what's the general rule then? If you were to only plot the 2nd and 3rd columns, you could just remove the `c3` and `c4` lines, and the script should work fine for any file with at least 3 columns.

Comment: Sorry if my question was not clear. I was just giving u an example. I can have a file of 17 columns too and I need to plot 1st col against 15th one. So general rule is to write a general script in python to automate number of cols. So I don't have to change my script each time I change number of cols in file or the column which I want to plot. Is it clear? thank for you help

Comment: How do you know which two columns you want to plot? As long as you don't explain this we can not help you ... or do you want to give this information as an argument to the script?

Comment: @plonser. Thank you for your respond. I want to give that as an argument to the script. Thank you again.

Comment: Any progress? Did the answer below help?